# How to get a value of a select input tag with options taken from a database using POST method?

Tags: php, html, forms, select

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <select name="doctor">
    <?php 
    $con = mysqli_connect("---","---","---","---") or die("Can't Connect to the Database.");
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Title, Name, LastName FROM physician");
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<option value=\"doctor1\">" . $row['Title'].' '.$row['Name'].' '.$row['LastName'] . "</option>";
    }

    ?>
    </select>
    &nbsp;<input type='submit' value="Filter"><br>
</form>
```

Above is a form I created. I used POST method. This form has a select input tag and it's options are taken from my database. When form is submitted I need to access the value selected by user using `$_POST['doctor']` function. But it doesn't give me any value. Can anyone help me?

Comment: When you submit the form the values will be in the POST array. Do yourself a favor, simply place a `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST)` in the PHP page which receives the form submission. Fill out your form, submit and look closely at the data printed to the screen. Familiarize yourself with how form data is posted to scripts, including what gets passed and what doesn't.

Comment: You defined `option value=\"doctor1\" ` for all options, but the value is what you get returned when POSTing your form. The stuff between the `<option></option>` tags is just for displaying it to the user. So what you want to do is to put the data you want returned in the `value` attribute. You usually use the `id` of the database entry, not the whole title, name and lastname for that.

Comment: Regardless of what the user responds with the entry will always be doctor1.

Comment: Please quit rolling back the edits, it makes your code disappear.

Comment: Thanks all for feedback. I wan't get the PhysicianID of physician table from the $_POST['doctor'] function. To do that what should be the option value in select option tag inside while loop?

Comment: You have to return the physician ID in the query, then you can make `value=\"". $row['physician_id'] . "\"`

Comment: and i think u are using `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` in php, NO name attribute in input type submit

Comment: I tried, echo "<option value="$row['PhysicianID']">" . $row['Title'].' '.$row['Name'].' '.$row['LastName'] . "</option>";

Comment: @devpro yes! I am using if(isset($_POST['submit']))

Comment: @JayBlanchard: check the last comment of OP :)

Comment: @AroshaMudalige: this will not work, you need to add name attribute as `<input type='submit' value="Filter" name='submit'>`

Comment: What a mess @devpro!

Comment: @Jay Blanchard  I tried it. And typed echo $_POST['doctor'] in action page. Then it displays nothing.

Comment: Did you change your query to get those values? All you're querying for now it Titke, Name and LastName. BTW, since I just wrote that out: `name` is a keyword for MySQL and would have to back ticked in queries if used as a column name in your table. Otherwise your query will fail. What columns are in your database table?

Comment: I need to get the value of $_POST['doctor'] as the PhysicianID of selected option by user. Here's my database. http://pasteboard.co/oLYnYAEfu.jpg

Comment: @Jay Blanchard Problem solved. Thanks a ton for your help. I forgot to select PhysicianID in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ID for each entry in the "physician" table is stored in a column "PhysicianID", you should try the following code snippet:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <select name="doctor">
        <?php 
            $con = mysqli_connect("---","---","---","---") or die("Can't Connect to the Database.");
            $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT PhysicianID, Title, Name, LastName FROM physician");
            while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
                echo '<option value="'.$row['PhysicianID'].'">'.$row['Title'].' '.$row['Name'].' '.$row['LastName'].'</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    &nbsp;<input type='submit' value="Filter"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. I forgot to select PhysicianID in the query. cheers!